# 2.79 and 2.80 on the same machine

Tags: modeling

I'm excited by the sound of Blender 2.80, but I'm reluctant to abandon 2.79 as I've spent so long learning it very slowly, (I'm 63). Can I load 2.80 without destroying 2.79? Will the blend files I made in 2.79 work in 2.80? PS: I don't expect to be able to run both at the same time.

Comment: Both even run at the same time and you can load 2.7x files so... no worries.

Comment: Careful, there have been instance were the 2.8 installer has overwritten the 2.79 install. Make sure to backup your settings first. The easiest way to use 2.8 risk free is the .zip download which doesn't require installation.

Comment: Thanks to both. I'll try the .zip download.